# Executor service doesn't process all data passed in arraylist

Tags: java, executorservice

I am trying to create a thread pool of 3 threads using `ExecutorService`, but whenever I process an `ArrayList` using these threads only second third and last element of the list gets processed by `run()` and then process gets stuck on last element and keeps processing it multiple times. This is my code:

```java
public ResponseEntity<?> syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3(List<Long> ids) {
    logger.info("Start :: syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3 for ids size = "+ids.size());
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    try {
        if (ids.size() > 0) {
            for (Long id : ids) {
                logger.info("id inside for"+id);
                ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons task = shopifyBulkSyncCoupons;
                task.setCouponId(id); // Set the 'id' value using the setter method
                service.execute(task);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    logger.info("End :: syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3");
    service.shutdown();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

This is my `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` class:

```java
@Component
public class ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        logger.info("Inside run for id "+CouponId);
        logger.info("ShopifyClientBean "+shopifyClient);

        PriceRuleService priceRuleService = new PriceRuleServiceImpl();

        ShopifyPriceRuleResponse priceRuleResponse = shopifyClient.getPriceRuleById(CouponId);
        if(null!=priceRuleResponse && null!=priceRuleResponse.getPriceRule()) {
            PriceRuleDetails priceRuleDetails = new PriceRuleDetails();
            List<Long> finalEntitledVariants = new ArrayList<>();
            priceRuleDetails = priceRuleService.mapShopifyPriceRuleToModel(priceRuleResponse.getPriceRule());
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledCollectionIds())) {
                List<Long> collectionIds = priceRuleDetails.getEntitledCollectionIds();
                List<ProductAttributes> prodAttr = productAttrRepository.findByCollectionsIn(collectionIds);
                for (ProductAttributes prod : prodAttr) {
                    finalEntitledVariants.add(prod.getVariantId());
                }
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledProductIds())) {
                List<ProductAttributes> productAttributesList = productAttrRepository.findByProductIdIn(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledProductIds());
                for (ProductAttributes prod : productAttributesList) {
                    finalEntitledVariants.add(prod.getVariantId());
                }
            }
            if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledVariantIds())) {
                finalEntitledVariants.addAll(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledVariantIds());
            }
priceRuleDetails.setEntitledVariantIds(finalEntitledVariants);
            priceRuleDetailsRepo.save(priceRuleDetails);
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried numerous ways to fix this. Can someone please help in identifying what is going wrong?

Comment: does it have anything to do with the ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons bean? Are you sure that it is running properly when you say it executes for second, third and last elements of the list? Since the bean is a singleton, and you set it for each and return the same bean, are you sure it runs "correctly"? it seems more like as it iterates, each of the threads are executing the same id which is the last one

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Do you suggest I should make the scope as Prototype for the bean ?

Comment: @ShreyaAggarwal, that would be 1 way to resolve your issue.

Comment: That won’t help if it continues to use the same instance for each iteration of the loop. It needs a new instance for each coupon ID.

Comment: What is `shopifyBulkSyncCoupons` exactly? I see no such variable anywhere. Is this a singleton? Are we calling `setCouponId` on the same object over and over again? Seems like we do not have enough information here to debug.

Comment: You call `task.setCouponId` but I see no `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons#setCopuonId` method on your `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` class.

Comment: When posting here, and when debugging, you should contrive some simplistic analog of your actual code, to detect where the original goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @BasilBourque shopifyBulkSyncCoupons is a bean . There is a stataement as 
         Autowired
 private ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons shopifyBulkSyncCoupons; in the beginning of the class . there is a setter method too to set CouponId in the ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons .

Comment: I will be happy to share more details . However this is the major chunk of the code .

Answer (score 1):

You have not given sufficient detail for us to debug, as noted in the Comments.

Most concerning are your two lines:

```java
ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons task = shopifyBulkSyncCoupons;
task.setCouponId(id);
```

We have no idea what is `shopifyBulkSyncCoupons`. I suspect you have a singleton object on which you are resetting the assigned coupon `id`. Changing a crucial value while having multiple threads operating on that singleton is a recipe for disaster.

## Example code

I can give you a skeleton of code paralleling your code.

The following code works successfully. I suggest adding to this skeleton piece by piece of your real work, until discovering the problem.

### Constructor on `Runnable`

Notice how our task, our `Runnable` implementation, below has a constructor taking as an argument the coupon id. That coupon id is then saved to a member variable of the task object.

This mean each of the multiple task objects we instantiate in a loop has its own coupon id value. No singleton, no changing an established value. To ensure no change, we mark both the parameter and the member field as `final`.

### Try-with-resources

Note that in modern Java, `ExecutorService` is `AutoCloseable`. So we can use try-with-resources syntax to properly shutdown the executor service.

Your Question's code was woefully short in that area — see the shutdown boilerplate given to you in the `ExecutorService` Javadoc. The default implementation of the `close` method added to `ExecutorService` is essentially a copy of that boilerplate.

### Avoid `execute`

Do not call `Executor#execute` on your `ExecutorService`. That method is documented as *maybe* executing the task on another thread *or* executing the task on the same thread. To ensure the use of background threads, call another method such as `submit`.

### Skeleton code

Define the task class:

```java
package work.basil.example.coupon;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class CouponProcessor implements Runnable
{
    private final Long couponId;

    public CouponProcessor ( final Long couponId ) { this.couponId = couponId; }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID # " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " starting to process coupon ID # " + this.couponId + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
        try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 1 , 7 ) ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
        System.out.println ( "Thread ID # " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " done process coupon ID # " + this.couponId + " at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }
}
```

And write an `App` class to process some coupon ids.

```java
package work.basil.example.coupon;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo starting at " + Instant.now ( ) );

        List < Long > couponIds = List.of ( 7L , 42L , 99L , 101L );  // Auto-boxing converts primitives to objects.
        try ( // Use try-with-resources syntax to automatically close the executor service when all submitted tasks have completed.
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool ( 3 ) ;
        )
        {
            for ( Long couponId : couponIds )
            {
                Runnable task = new CouponProcessor ( couponId );
                executorService.submit ( task );
            }
        }
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Executor service shutdown at " + Instant.now ( ) );

        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo done at " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
INFO - Demo starting at 2023-09-22T06:00:22.962114Z
Thread ID # 22 starting to process coupon ID # 42 at 2023-09-22T06:00:22.966858Z
Thread ID # 23 starting to process coupon ID # 99 at 2023-09-22T06:00:22.966860Z
Thread ID # 21 starting to process coupon ID # 7 at 2023-09-22T06:00:22.966859Z
Thread ID # 22 done process coupon ID # 42 at 2023-09-22T06:00:27.051596Z
Thread ID # 22 starting to process coupon ID # 101 at 2023-09-22T06:00:27.053034Z
Thread ID # 21 done process coupon ID # 7 at 2023-09-22T06:00:27.980626Z
Thread ID # 23 done process coupon ID # 99 at 2023-09-22T06:00:28.051538Z
Thread ID # 22 done process coupon ID # 101 at 2023-09-22T06:00:31.125844Z
INFO - Executor service shutdown at 2023-09-22T06:00:31.135371Z
INFO - Demo done at 2023-09-22T06:00:31.136004Z
```

Beware: Output from `System.out.println` does *not* necessarily appear on the console in chronological order when called across threads. If you care about the order, include a timestamp to be studied. Or else gather the messages into a thread-safe collection rather than feeding to `println` calls.

### Virtual threads

In Java 21+, if your task involves [blocking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_%28computing%29) (is not entirely [CPU-bound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound)), use [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444).

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
```

Comment: The line Runnable task = new CouponProcessor ( couponId ); causes issue as below Autowiring doesn't work and all the bean shopifyClient become null
Service
public class PriceRuleServiceImpl implements PriceRuleService {
 private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PriceRuleServiceImpl.class);

 Autowired
 private ShopifyClient shopifyClient;

Comment: @ShreyaAggarwal I just did a `clean` and rebuild. Runs fine. Start with just my code. Then bring over parts of yours, getting each working. Don't aim for real work, aim for simulated work, taking baby steps.

Comment: And you made no mention of auto wiring in your Question. If you are using Spring, CDI, or such, you should note that in the Question.

Comment: if I will use a constructor the bean is null . I will require that bean for further executions in code . Won't doing Runnable task = new CouponProcessor ( couponId ); create a new instance that will not be a spring instantiated instance so that instance will not be able to make use of autowired annotations .

Comment: Then, wouldnt it make more sense to create a bean that creates and returns a new runnable for you when you pass it a couponId rather than create a bean that is itself the runnable?